# Серверный таймер?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, yii2, websocket

Есть такая ситуация, сейчас делаю аукцион и возникла проблема, окончание лота происходит по окончанию времени. Сейчас у меня реализовано вот так:

```
$("#getting-started")
        .countdown("<?=$lot->time?>", function(event) {
            $(this).text(
                event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
            );
        }).on('finish.countdown', function(){
            $.ajax({
            url: '/site/lottimeend',
            type: 'post',
            data:{id: <?=$lot->id?>, status: true},
            success: function (response) {
               if(response == 0){
                $('#p_time_end_single').removeClass("p_hidden_time");
                $('#p_wadium_button').addClass("p_hidden_time");
                $('#p_main_content_time_end').addClass("p_hidden_time");
                $('#getting-started').addClass("p_hidden_time");
               }
            }
        });
    });
```

Но проблема в том, что если эта страница не открыта, то js код не выполнится и лот не закончится, в поиске ничего толкового не нашел. Не могу понять в какую сторону смотреть,может какой серверный таймер но по такому запросы информации очень мало, в проекте использую yii2, nodejs, redis.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас эта страница на PHP - то скрипты выполняются только один раз. Тогда вам нужно создать событие cron, выполняющееся каждые N минут, которое будет грузить php скрипт. А в этом скрипте пробегать по всем товарам и выставлять что торги окончены.

Если используете NodeJS - то тогда можете сделать то же самое без cron - просто через setInterval каждые N минут выполнять то же самое - проходим по всем товарам и выставляем за которые торги окончены. Можно же просто грузить нужную страницу.